# How to install box cutter if it isn't found in add on?

Tags: add-on, installation

I have installed blender latest version 2.90.1 and I need box cutter application but it is not available in add on. Now I am helpless because I have no idea to get the box cutter in blender. I have searched for it many times on YouTube but not a single video exactly matches with my problem.

Comment: Boxcutter is a commercial addon, you have to buy it

Answer (score 1):

https://blendermarket.com/products/boxcutter

Once purchased, Follow the guide to install into blender. Boxcutter is a paid addon and cant be installed from the default addon directory.

Manual: https://boxcutter-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your point to point answer

Comment: If that answers your question, consider to mark it as accepted @sagar How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour